# Saving remote image with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, webkit, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1 on Ubuntu *without* Node or Casper.

```
fs.write('images/products/image.jpg', 'http://example.com/folder/someimage.jpg', 'w');
```

.. although this creates 1xx byte jpeg files that aren't really images. Is there a way to download any type of (JPEG, JPG, PNG) file with PhantomJS?

Comment: Does the `/folder/` in the given url `'http://example.com/folder/someimage.jpg'` has all the `read/write/` permissions set?

Comment: @DavidR Yes it does. Thats why the files are created but they aren't really images.

Comment: This code creates a file with the *content*: 'http://example.com/folder/someimage.jpg'. You need to actually load the image and then write it to the file.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Oh, what PhantomJS method would that be, can you please point me to an example?

Comment: There is none. You'd use `page.evaluate` to use the page context where you'd make an Ajax request to get the image contents, then encode it in some good way, pass it out of the page context, decode it to binary and write to the file. I can't find the duplicate right now, but I know there is one.

Comment: it's very interesting method of downloading images, I'd use curl, wget or whatever else, but you can do it with PhantomJS, for sure, like here https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13657
I believe you have to render the image in PhantomJs, as it's a headless browser, then select some area (clip) and save it

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have the image URL already so its about encode and then decoding the image then I believe.

Comment: @vitr Oh, I did think about wget .. would that be faster than via PhantomJS? so `shell_exec` get stdout, explode it to array, foreach .. shell_exec again for `wget` ?

Comment: yes, definitely faster, see PhantomJS as your browser, you can save image as... or you can make a screenshot of an image and save it, which is exactly what you're trying to do here

Comment: wget saves to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way to do this, in which PhantomJS saves an image by itself:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 800 };
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36';

var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
var selector = "#hlogo a";

page.open(url, function(){

    setTimeout(function(){

        var clipRect = page.evaluate(function (selector) { 
            return document.querySelector(selector).getBoundingClientRect(); 
        }, selector);

        page.clipRect = {
            top:    clipRect.top,
            left:   clipRect.left,
            width:  clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height
        };

        page.render('image.jpg');

        phantom.exit();

    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: This is a native PhantomJS script, no node.js stuff.

Comment: Cool and what if the image is larger than the viewport? It most probably will be. So should I set the viewport to the largest resolution? Would that affect performance?

Comment: Good point, haven't thought of that. Yes you could set a very large viewport size and yes it will affect performance. A workaround could be this: subscribe to [page.onResourceRecieved](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) callback and save raw data if its URL is what you need, BUT currently raw data is not included in callback. But there is a fork with that functionality returned: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10158#issuecomment-237301347

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
$stdout = shell_exec("phantomjs ./scrape-images.js '".$url);
$images = isset($stdout) ? explode(',', $stdout) : '';
```

.. then:

```
$command = 'wget '.urlencode($image).' --output-document="/path/to/image/directory/'.$filename.'" --quiet --background >/dev/null 2>&1';
shell_exec($command);
```

**Edit**: The only downside is that some websites detect `wget` and throw a 404 (even though I pass a useragent and a referer) for not being a *real* user whereas Phantom would've gotten away with it.